# Haskell giving "Variable not in scope: [Integer] -> t

Tags: function, haskell, helper, tracker

I am just trying to make a simple function that takes a list and makes sure that the numbers are in ascending order in it.

```
`ascending :: Ord t => [t] -> Bool
ascending [] = True
ascending (x:xs) = (tracker xs x)

tracker :: Ord t => [t] -> t -> Bool
tracker [] y = True
tracker (x:xs) y | if y <= x = True
                 | otherwise = False`
```

This is what I have so far but I am getting "Variable not in scope: ascending :: [Integer] -> t
"
I cannot figure out how to fix this for some reason

Comment: Looks like you are calling `ascending` somewhere without importing it. Furthermore the `tracker` will only check if the first element is less than or equal to the second, not if the remaining elements are in ascending order.

Comment: There is also a syntax error in your program, the `if` should not be used in case of a guard.

Comment: Don't enter your code line-by-line in GHCi. Save it in a file and load the whole file with `:l FileName.hs` in GHCi.

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error in your program, the `if` should not be used in case of a guard. You thus can fix the syntax error with:

```
tracker :: Ord t => [t] -> t -> Bool
tracker [] y = True
tracker (x:xs) y | y <= x = True
                 | otherwise = False
```

But this `tracker` is not sufficient to check if the *entire* list is in ascending order, it will only check if the first *two* elements are in ascending order. In case `y <= x`, you should recurse on the rest of the list to check if that is in ascending order as well. You can for example write this as:

```
tracker :: Ord t => [t] -> t -> Bool
tracker [] y = True
tracker (x:xs) y = y <= x && tracker xs x
```